# Style graduated: Clases yes, Illustartion no

Tags: qgis, style

I joined "1980" (Fields on foto) with ¨municipal¨ (the blue one graduate) through ¨CVEGEO¨ value. Then I tried to illustrate with graduate style the  AUTO_PARTICULAR value.

Result: There is a clasification but not the illustration.

Before the aplication of graduate style, I had an another graduate style illustration of a value but of the same table of ¨municipal¨, that was good.

The problem is with the joined table. I recently imported through ¨Add Delimited Text Layer¨ with a .csvt file.

[image: picture A]

Comment: there is no geometry in that layer

Comment: but there is in ¨municipal¨ the joined one. When i do it with a value of municipal i do have an illustration. But when i choose one of the joined table ¨1980¨ the is no an illustration

Comment: Which columns are you using in the join? and are you joining the "1980" to "municipal" or the other way around?

Comment: I joined 1980 to municipal. And I used the column AUTO_PARTICULAR

Comment: I think you may need to edit some more to try and keep this in the review queue so that it can be re-opened when ready.  I am a desktop GIS user (not QGIS) but what you are asking is not yet clear to me.

Comment: There is no geometry because the image shows the structure of the external database. Can you show the results of the join and how do you want to be clasified?